# CUDA C++: Expected an expression in kernel.cu file

Tags: c++, cuda

I just started learning a bit of CUDA, and I encountered this error in the following line, at a <<< >>> expression

```
#include "kernels.h"
#include "helpers.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
__global__
void blur(unsigned char* input_image, unsigned char* output_image, int width, int height) {

    const unsigned int offset = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int x = offset % width;
    int y = (offset - x) / width;
    int fsize = 5; // Filter size
    if (offset < width*height) {

        float output_red = 0;
        float output_green = 0;
        float output_blue = 0;
        int hits = 0;
        for (int ox = -fsize; ox < fsize + 1; ++ox) {
            for (int oy = -fsize; oy < fsize + 1; ++oy) {
                if ((x + ox) > -1 && (x + ox) < width && (y + oy) > -1 && (y + oy) < height) {
                    const int currentoffset = (offset + ox + oy * width) * 3;
                    output_red += input_image[currentoffset];
                    output_green += input_image[currentoffset + 1];
                    output_blue += input_image[currentoffset + 2];
                    hits++;
                }
            }
        }
        output_image[offset * 3] = output_red / hits;
        output_image[offset * 3 + 1] = output_green / hits;
        output_image[offset * 3 + 2] = output_blue / hits;
    }
}


void filter(unsigned char* input_image, unsigned char* output_image, int width, int height) {

    unsigned char* dev_input;
    unsigned char* dev_output;
    getError(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_input, width*height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char)));
    getError(cudaMemcpy(dev_input, input_image, width*height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    getError(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_output, width*height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char)));

    dim3 blockDims(512, 1, 1);
    dim3 gridDims((unsigned int)ceil((double)(width*height * 3 / blockDims.x)), 1, 1);

    blur <<< gridDims, blockDims >>>(dev_input, dev_output, width, height);


    getError(cudaMemcpy(output_image, dev_output, width*height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    getError(cudaFree(dev_input));
    getError(cudaFree(dev_output));
}
```

In the

```
blur <<< gridDims, blockDims >>>(dev_input, dev_output, width, height);
```

line, at the third < in it, I encounter the error from the title, and because of it I can't compile the code (Other people said that it is an Intellisense error, but for other people the program compilled, while mine doesn't).

I also receive this error when I try to compile

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3721 The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2017 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\Artyomska\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ScreenFilter\ScreenFilter\kernel.cu"" exited with code 1. ScreenFilter    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 9.1.targets    707
```

I am trying to run the program on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 (the latest version, with toolkit for 15.4 support installed so I don't receive incompatible version error). I have tried reinstalling CUDA 9.1.85, VS2017 and create a new project. I added paths in dependencies and libraries to the NVIDIA Toolkit, and that code is present in a .cu file.

The problem is that even if I create a new project, without changing anything and letting kernel.cu with how the default settings populate it, it still has the expression error at a <<< >>> line.

What should I do to resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you confusing an intellisense error with an actual compilation error? The error message you posted is meaningless. You need to increase the VS verbosity in order to see what actually happened

Comment: can you compile other CUDA samples? don't know if it matters but I'd put the __global__ moniker in front of the blur function. Clearly the code is not picked up by NVCC, but this can be tricky with CMake (given the formatting of the error I think you are using CMake) since NVCC atually uses the c++ toolkit to compile the non-cuda bits. Check what is going on by running the command from the command-line again

Comment: Get your error messages from the Output window. The Error List is not as useful as Microsoft thinks.

Comment: Putting global in another place didn't worked. Also I can't run any of the samples, receiving many errors in them :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. The newest version of VS2017 doesn't support the newest version of CUDA, so the solution was to do what it's told in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/15/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2017/). Now everything works

Comment: So it was an Intellisense error. If you had the verbosity level set higher you would have seen the actual error from nvcc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same compile time error. Right click on the file in visual studio->Properties->Configuration Properties->Item Type (Set this as CUDA C/C++)

Answer (score 0):

Since I have experienced this error MANY times, I just wanted to add that if you see this error shown with any other errors make sure that you take care of other errors first. It is very likely that this error is not the actual cause of your failed compilation though it may show up as the first error on the list of errors.